# Exclude geographic extent of an OSM file

Tags: openstreetmap, osmosis, osmium

Osmium and Osmosis command tools have the capability of extracting a geographic extent from an OSM file.

```
osmosis 
--read-xml test.osm --tee 1
--bounding-box left=15 top=46 --write-xml extract_test.osm

osmium extract -p city.geojson test.pbf -o extract_test.pbf
```

What I need is to extract region from an OSM file like a city and after some edits, merge it with the OSM file with the hole (excluded the city region). How can I exclude or clip a geographic extent from original file?

Answer (score 0):

GeoJSON polygons are [allowed to have holes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946#section-3.1.6), and Osmium does in fact support this.

So you could construct a polygon where ...

- ... the outer ring is large enough to contain all the data in the original file
- ... the inner ring is the boundary of the city you want to exclude.

Running `osmium extract` with that polygon as the `-p` parameter would remove data inside the inner ring and yield the desired result.